# how to plot images from list with image paths

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have a list of photos with their location.

'''

```
my_list =['test_photos\\36.jpg','test_photos\\5.jpg','test_photos\\38.jpg','test_photos\\9.jpg','test_photos\\27.jpg','test_photos\\8.jpg','test_photos\\24.jpg','test_photos\\32.jpg','test_photos\\18.jpg']
```

How do I plot them on grid with 3 columns and 3 rows so plot displays all 9 photos?

Comment: Try using the subplots of the matplotlib. The other alternatives to look for are the seaborn and plotly

Comment: I know how to plot an image, just don't know how to do that from python list

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use python Pillow lib.

first you'd better resize the images using resize function.

Then you can concatenate them vertically or horizontally .

I give you 2 links , I wish it helps .

first step :[resize the images](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-resize-method/)
second     :[concat images](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-concat-images/)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.